# I can't copy Public properties to an external file form CustomAction on WiX

Tags: wix

I'm trying to copy the value of a public property (which are set from CMD) to an external text file, but it's returning the property name not the value:

```
<Property Id='PROP1'/>
<Property Id='PROP2'/>
<Property Id="CA_DOTNETCA_OnInstall_BeforeInstallingFiles" Value="PROP1=[PROP1];PROP2=[PROP2]" />
<CustomAction Id="CA_DOTNETCA_OnInstall_BeforeInstallingFiles" BinaryKey="BIN_DOTNETCustomActions" DllEntry="CA_OnInstall_BeforeInstallingFiles" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
```

MyCustomAction :

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CA_OnInstall_BeforeInstallingFiles(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            CustomActionData data = session.CustomActionData;

            string createText = "text : " + data["PROP1"] + " " + data["PROP2"];
            File.WriteAllText("c:/text.txt", createText);

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Display message to user
            Record record = new Record(0);
            record.SetString(0, ex.Message);
            session.Message(InstallMessage.Error, record);

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

and this is the output content of text file :

```
text : [PROP1] [PROP2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using a property element instead of a setproperty element.  The property element maps to the property table and it doesn't do string formatting so the literals [PROP1] [PROP2] are being used.   Instead use a custom action to SetProperty and it will be properly formatted.

PS- The good news is your using a deferred custom action which is good since you are writing a file to the machine.  But the thing that stands out to me is you didn't mark the properties PROP1 and PROP2 as Secure.  In some situations this would cause the installer to reject the properties being passed to it.

Comment: even when using secure properties, it does not work, can you provide a code sample please ?

Comment: [Here is a sample on deferred mode](https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXDeferredModeSample) - not exactly what you asked, but it might help. There is [another sample on deferred mode using DTF here](https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXDeferredModeSampleDTF). It is a little bit more advanced - using a feature from DTF (part of WiX toolkit) to send properties to deferred mode.